# How can I get a reference to a Fragment in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The only documented way I found is:

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

But since the Fragment is instantiated in a ViewPager I don't have an id.

```
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment3.class.getName()));
```

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here. Seems to be solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be holding all fragments in memory in an oh-so-obsolete `Vector`. In that case, you would retrieve your fragment out of that same `Vector`. For example, call `getCurrentItem()` on the `ViewPager` to find the currently-selected fragment index, then call `get()` on the `Vector` with that index.

Note, though, that if you are relying on `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to hold your fragments, that a fragment for a given index may not exist, either because it has not been created yet or it has been discarded to minimize memory consumption.

(BTW, see [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-java-vector-class-is-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated) for more on `Vector`)