# How to restart Loader in a ListFragment from a FragmentActivity tha uses ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I have a `ViewPager` `FragmentActivity` that holds 3 tabs, Each one of the tabs is a `ListFragment` that has a Loader.
In the initialization of this activity all the loaders load, so far so good.

I implemented a public method `refresh()` in the fragment that restarts the loader: `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);`

When I call it from the parent activity it throws `illegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity`.
Any ideas how can I restart the loader?

Edit:

My activity extends `SherlockFragmentActicity` and in it I have an adapter that extends `FragmentPagerAdapter` to menage the tabs in the pager.

```
public class UserPageFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
   ...

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_CHANNELS).setIndicator("Following"),
            UserPageListFragmentChannels.class, null);
   ...

     public void refresh(){

           switch (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()){
                     case CHANNELS:
                              ((UserPageListFragmentChannels)mTabsAdapter.getItem(CHANNELS)).refresh();
                              break;
        ...
           }

     }

}
```

now the tab fragment is:

```
public class UserPageListFragmentChannels extends SherlockListFragment implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Void> {

...
    public void refresh(){
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);        
    }
...


}
```

Comment: If you're using the support Library, call `getSupportLoaderManager()` instead of `getLoaderManager()`

Comment: I tried to extend ListFragment or SherlockListFragment, they both take getLoaderManager() and not getSupportLoaderManager(). The error that I get now is illegalStateException Fragment not attached to Activity...

Comment: Updated the exception I got. Edited post.

Comment: Well thats odd. `getSupportLoaderManager()` should be what it takes because it uses the support library by default, meaning you shouldn't be using `getLoaderManager()`. I say post some of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after digging a little bit more I found the solution here from "barkside": [Update data in ListFragment as part of ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager)

I implement it the same in my activity's refresh():

```
UserPageListFragmentChannels fragment =  
              (UserPageListFragmentChannels) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":0"); 
          if(fragment != null)  // could be null if not instantiated yet 
          { 
             if(fragment.getView() != null)  
             { 
                // no need to call if fragment's onDestroyView()  
                //has since been called. 
                fragment.refresh(); // do what updates are required 
             } 
          }
```