# refresh viewpager, lsitfragment or adapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, baseadapter, android-listfragment

i have a main class that hold a actionbarsherlock with tabs and viewpager

here is it:

```
public class HSG_Handball extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    TextView tabCenter;
    TextView tabText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

        setContentView(mViewPager);
        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Alle Spiele"), Spiele.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tabelle"), Tabelle.class, null);
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
    {
        private final Context mContext;
        private final ActionBar mActionBar;
        private final ViewPager mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

        static final class TabInfo
        {
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle args;

            TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args)
            {
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager)
        {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
            mViewPager = pager;
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
        {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return mTabs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)
        {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)
        {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
            Object tag = tab.getTag();
            for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++)
            {
                if (mTabs.get(i) == tag)
                {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
        {
        }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {

        SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Aktive");
        subMenu1.add("Herren 1");
        subMenu1.add("Herren 2");
        subMenu1.add("Herren 3");
        subMenu1.add("Damen 1");
        subMenu1.add("Damen 2");

        MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        SubMenu subMenu2 = menu.addSubMenu("Jugend");
        subMenu2.add("männl. A");
        subMenu2.add("weibl. A");
        subMenu2.add("männl. B1");
        subMenu2.add("männl. B2");
        subMenu2.add("männl. C");
        subMenu2.add("männl. D");
        subMenu2.add("E-Jugend");

        MenuItem subMenu2Item = subMenu2.getItem();
        subMenu2Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(!item.getTitle().toString().equals("Active") || !item.getTitle().toString().equals("Jugend"))
        {
            new Spiele().FormatiereSpieleSeite(item.getTitle().toString());
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the second class (Spiele) is a listfragment with a custom base adapter.
The class looks so:

public class Spiele extends ListFragment 
{

```
String ligaId = "0";
SpieleAdapterFuerCustomList adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spiele, container, false);

        List<String> dateAndSchiri = new ArrayList<String>();
        dateAndSchiri.add("DATUM  ·  Schiri 1 : Schiri 2");
        dateAndSchiri.add("DATUM  ·  Schiri 1 : Schiri 2");
        dateAndSchiri.add("DATUM  ·  Schiri 1 : Schiri 2");

        List<String> heim = new ArrayList<String>();
        heim.add("HSG Nieder-Roden");
        heim.add("SG Bruchköbel");
        heim.add("LOL Idiotenklupp");

        List<String> gast = new ArrayList<String>();
        gast.add("KG Wallau");
        gast.add("DJ G4bby");
        gast.add("Hanzup Motherf*ckers");

        adapter = new SpieleAdapterFuerCustomList(getActivity(), dateAndSchiri, heim, gast);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
}

public void FormatiereSpieleSeite(String mannschaft)
    {
// aktive
        if(mannschaft.equals("Herren 1"))
            ligaId = "X0";
        if(mannschaft.equals("Herren 2"))
            ligaId = "00151350asd0";
        if(mannschaft.equals("Herren 3"))
            ligaId = "00151asdad000000000000000001000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("Damen 1"))
            ligaId = "001513asdad0000000007000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("Damen 2"))
            ligaId = "0015135asd0000000000003000";

// jugend
        if(mannschaft.equals("männl. A"))
            ligaId = "0015135asdasd0000000000001000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("weibl. A"))
            ligaId = "";
        if(mannschaft.equals("männl. B1"))
            ligaId = "001513asdasd0000000000000002000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("männl. B2"))
            ligaId = "00151350asd05502000000000000001000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("männl. C"))
            ligaId = "0015asdasd503000000000000001000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("männl. D"))
            ligaId = "001513504501asdsad0000001000";
        if(mannschaft.equals("E-Jugend"))
            ligaId = "0015135asdasd000000000003000";



    System.out.println(ligaId + "Das ist liga");

    List<String> dateAndSchiri = new ArrayList<String>();
    dateAndSchiri.add("DATUM as Schiri 2");
    dateAndSchiri.add("DATUMasas Schisdfsdfri 2");
    dateAndSchiri.add("DATUMasas Schirsdfsfi 2");

    List<String> heim = new ArrayList<String>();
    heim.add("HSG Nieder-sdfRoden");
    heim.add("SG Brucsdfhköbel");
    heim.add("LOL Idiosdfsdftenklupp");

    List<String> gast = new ArrayList<String>();
    gast.add("KG Walsdfsflau");
    gast.add("DJ G4sdfsfbby");
    gast.add("Hanzusdfsfp Motherf*ckers");

    adapter = new SpieleAdapterFuerCustomList(getActivity(), dateAndSchiri, heim, gast);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

All is ok and run fine.

On the "main"-class. The class that holds the viewpager and tabsactionbar have menus. If the user click on one of them it must load a new ListFragment. Or a new BaseAdapter(?).
I want that the ListFragment (class: Spiele) is updatet. 
But how can i do that?
How update my ListFragment?

Comment: now one with an idea?! i know i must call notifyDateSetChanged() but where and of what? Of the BAseAdapter, the ListFragment or ViewPager?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is easyer than i think.

These https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393477/1231245 have helped me to find the FragmentTag from the first Fragment in ViewPager.

I can easilie create and set the adapter in the onOptionsItemSelected method.
Here is it:

```
        List<String> dateAndSchiri = new ArrayList<String>();
        dateAndSchiri.add.....

        List<String> heim = new ArrayList<String>();
        heim.add.....

        List<String> gast = new ArrayList<String>();
        gast.add.....

        SpieleAdapterFuerCustomList adapter = new SpieleAdapterFuerCustomList(getBaseContext(), dateAndSchiri, heim, gast);
        Spiele articleFrag = (Spiele) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:"+R.id.pager+":0");
        articleFrag.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

you can create a new adapter with different ArrayList's with different click on menu...

Answer (score 0):

Why this ArrayList with TabInfo? Why not use an ArrayList with Fragments directly. And not in the adapter but in the Activity itself?

In this case you could do something like this:

1.

```
public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args)
{
   tab.setTabListener(this);
   Fragment f = Fragment.instantiate(mContext, clss.getName(), args);
   mFragments.add(f);
   mActionBar.addTab(tab);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

2.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    if(!item.getTitle().toString().equals("Active") || !item.getTitle().toString().equals("Jugend"))
    {
        Fragment f = mFragments.get(getSupportActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition());
        ((Spiele)f).FormatiereSpieleSeite(item.getTitle().toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

If I understand you correctly all you want to do is change the adapter. Right?

Comment: i dont know what i need to update. i have the code from here https://bitbucket.org/owentech/abstabsviewpager/src

Comment: Well, did you try replacing these methods and using an ArrayList of Fragments instead of TabInfos?

Comment: I can swipe very well between tabs. But I forgot to mention that I changed the `getItem()` method as well to just this one line: `return mFragments.get(position);` That of course has to be added to swipe :-)