# FragmentManager give me the wrong fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using this line to get the current fragment displayed :

```
Item myFragment = (Item) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
```

Here is an example of my ViewPager

> | A | B | C | D | E | F |

The first fragment displayed is A, but myFragment is B
When I go to B, myFragment = B
...
When I go to F, myFragment = E
You can see the code here : -> [TabsActivity.java](https://github.com/guitoun3/SortirSurBordeaux/blob/master/Sortir%20sur%20bordeaux/src/com/guillaumedesbieys/sortirsurbordeaux/activity/TabsActivity.java)

Someone has already got this problem ?
Why there is a shift between the fragment displayed and the value of myFragment ?

Thanks

[EDIT]
I add a Log()
Now here is a part of my TabsActivity

```
class TabsAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {

    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.e("POSITION", position + "");
        return Item.newInstance(CONTENT.get(position % CONTENT.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return CONTENT.get(position % CONTENT.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return CONTENT.size();
    }
}
```

And when I start my application my logger display : 
POSITION 0
POSITION 1

Is it normal ? It shouldn't be only "POSITION 0" displayed ? 
And when I slide, "POSITION 1" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're asking for fragments based on the ID.  The ID `R.id.pager` is just some random number that's linked to whatever `R.id.pager` is.  In the code provided, you're not assigning an ID to any of your Fragments, so the fact that you're getting anything is lucky.

If you want to retrieve a Fragment from a Viewpager, then you need to follow the criteria answered in this question: [Update data in ListFragment as part of ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager)

Second, the reason you're getting "POSITION 0 POSITION 1" is because the `ViewPager` retrieves the current page **plus any other page that is in the immediate vicinity that it does not already have**.  This means that it's calling `getItem()` on the current page, the previous page, and the next page.  At position 0, there is no previous page, but there is a next page.  If you swipe over, you'll only see `POSITION 2` because the ViewPager needs to create `POSITION 2` in preparation of the next swipe.  If you were to jump to item 4, you'll see `POSITION 2 POSITION 3 POSITION 4`.

Comment: Now it's clear for the second part ;) Thanks
And I solve my problem by recording index when I instanciate my fragment. Like here [link]http://tamsler.blogspot.nl/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html