# ViewPager offscreen fragment

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager which is used to display images or videos. So it uses two fragments. One fragment has ImageView and the other one has VideoView.

So when a user is watching a movie and swipes to another fragment I want the video to stop playing in the now offscreen fragment.

How can I do this?

Comment: Here is the solution I needed:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886019/1143354

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), it will give you the way to take action when the user goes from one page to another.

You set it by using [setOnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29)

Comment: I knew about the OnPageChangeListener. The problem was how to get the current fragment so I could change it's properties. 
Found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886019/1143354

Comment: I see... that part would depend on the PagerAdapter you are using (and how you implement it). Most of the time, I keep references to the different fragments I have separately (an Array for example), so that's usually not a problem.

Comment: I am using 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' because there can be a lot of video or image files and this adapter cleans its views.
So that is why I don't know if it's OK to keep references to fragments.

Comment: (I think) it's always ok to keep references to the fragments, only when you use them, you should check that getView() or getActivity() does not return null whenever you use them... the reference to the fragment is not going to change.