# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement fragment communication in android like the one in the android guide http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

but my application is crashing as the  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById() returns null. What is the issue with my implementation.

The code is given below:

The program is just to send an input text from one fragment to another fragment textView area through a button click from first fragmnet.I have an activity_main.xml and two fragment layout (two separate xml files rather than part of  in activity_main.xml)

Frag1.java

```
public class Frag1 extends Fragment {
public Frag1(){

}

buttonClickListener buttonListener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
try {
    buttonListener = (buttonClickListener) getActivity();
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnButtonPressListener");
}
}

View myFragmentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);


    //SetValue Button
    Button setValueButton = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.setValueButton);
    setValueButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttonListener.onButtonPressed("Message received");
        }
    });


    return myFragmentView;
}
```

}

Frag2.java

```
public class Frag2 extends Fragment {

View myFragmentView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2, container, false);
    return myFragmentView;
}

void setMessage(String msg){
    TextView txt=(TextView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txt.setText(msg);
}
}
```

buttonClickListener.java

```
public interface buttonClickListener {
public void onButtonPressed(String msg);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener, buttonClickListener {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
@Override
public void onButtonPressed(String msg) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Frag2 fragmentObj=(Frag2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.layout.frag2);


    fragmentObj.setMessage(msg);
}
```

Please tell me where did I go wrong?

EDIT: 
I am using fragment creation using the template generated by Android Plug-in eclipse IDE.
So the fragments are created using **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch(position)
        {
        case 0:
            return new Frag1();
        case 1: 
            return new Frag2();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

The codebase is kept here for reference
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=D37E0F56FEC9B499!259

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock, Support library or what?

Comment: findFragmentById(R.layout.frag2).
Are you sure about R.layout.flag2, may be R.id.frag2

Comment: @gipi I have used support lib and the same has been updated in my EDIT.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti : I haven't added id to the fragment elements as they are part of layout and not present in <fragment> element.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should have added the fragment **Frag2** by calling

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag2_view, new Frag2(), "tag").commit();
```

at your **MainActivity**, where `R.id.frag2_view` is a layout defined in your main_layout.

To get that Fragment, you should then call

```
Frag2 obj = (Frag2)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag2_view);
```

passing the layout **id** you used to add the fragment in the main_layout.

Hope it helps.

EDIT:

Since you use a ViewPager, you should use **R.id.pager** as the ID.
I just tried with your example and it worked.

```
Frag2 fragmentObj=(Frag2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
```

EDIT 2:

Despite it worked, I don't really think this is the correct way, since R.id.pager its from ViewPager and you can't find, let's say, **frag4** or **frag5**.

Ignore my answer please. I'm not sure how to do that with ViewPager, sorry.

Comment: I am using **Fragment getItem** to put the fragments. So how should i apply your approach? I'm new to android(just 3 days old) :)

Comment: @Kris I just updated my answer based on your question update. I didn't know you were using ViewPager. Let me know if it works.

Comment: After the second edit I have unmarked the answer but I feel its useful. I will try to find an alternative approach/wait for the correct method ..

Comment: Check out this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8886019/2174489). He uses `Frag2 fragmentObj=(Frag2) mSectionsPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, 1);` which seems to work

Comment: thanks for the help @Eduardo Herzer I have updated the answer with your last comment.(has to be peer reviewed.. :))

Answer (score 24):

Try This it works for me [How to put Google Maps V2 on a Fragment Using ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager)

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

GoogleMap mGoogleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: For me using getChildFragmentManger() was the fix.  I was attempting to retrieve fragments from a fragment i.e. the fragments were children of the fragment where I was calling findFragmentById()

Answer (score 7):

I was having a similar problem and here is the solution.
To get the reference to the proper fragment inside the viewpager just call:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

The tag param you can build it using the following syntax: `"android:switcher:pager_id:index"`, where `pager_id` is the id of the ViewPager in the XML layout and the index is the position of your fragment inside the `ViewPager` starting by zero. See the original response here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7393477/2423274

Answer (score 5):

Found the **right solution** for this question.

Hope more people see this.

```
Frag2 fragmentObj=(Frag2) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(2);
```

You should use your Adapter (where you populate your fragments) as a source for get the Fragment reference.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to get a child fragment from a fragment adapter...

```
Fragment parent = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
        if (parent instanceof PagerFragment) {
            // do something with parent
            Fragment child = ((PagerFragment) f).adapter.getItem(childPosition);
        }
```