# Viewpager+FragmentpagerAdapet+Fragments+Listview = insanely slow app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, google-play, viewpagerindicator

I have a viewpager in my layout , that viewpager holds a set of 10 fragments . Each fragment has a list view , which is asynchronously populated .  I m currently using  FragmentPagerAdapter as adapter for the viewpager and the API calls to populate the list view is done in onCreateView of each fragment . The swipe is insanely slow and app closes itself because of the memory issues .

How to achieve smooth and responsive (viewpager+listview) like Google Play does ? 
Smooth swiping + good cache of list items ?

[image]

Comment: One more thing that i would like to add in this question can i achieve viewpager in fragment if yes then how??

Answer (score 13):

There are many ways to improve the performance of a `ViewPager` integrated with a `ListView`.

First, change the `PagerAdapter` from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The difference is that you load 10 pages within the pager. And if you went through all the manager will only put the pages in `onStop()` therefore it will reserve space. However using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will destroy these pages but will save their instance using the `onSaveInstanceState` method. So when you get back it won't take much time to load and you will be saving memory.

Usually `FragmentPagerAdapter` is used with 3 pages or less.

The second way to improve performance (but it drains the battery faster) is adding this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml` under your application tag:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

The third way is detecting the swipe gesture. You can do this by implementing `onPageChangeListener` then in the implemented method `onPageScrollStateChanged` you check if the page is `Idle` then add the `ListView`. Otherwise, stop the use of `ListView` and scroll to the next page. Here is a better [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644853/viewpager-adapter-in-fragment-laggy-swiping) of this point.

Hope some of these points can help you out to achieve better performance.

Comment: Hi , if i use onPageChangeListener then each time i swipe to the page , it will make api calls and populate it . How can i cache the results . My api calls will return me a JSON .