# Viewpager Recyclerview scroll lag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement viewpager for the mainpage having 4 fragments (fixed). The fragments on their own aren't lagging (and I am sure of this cause they were previously implemented through navigation drawer ).The fragments contain recyclerview which is lagging. It contains images . For loading the images I am using Glide. I've tried setEnabledNestedScrollingEnabled to false , but no such luck.For test purposes I was just testing with one fragment , even then it was lagging.

MainActivity

```
package com.example.anubhavr.firebase;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.fragment_one, R.drawable.fragment_two, R.drawable.fragment_three, R.drawable.fragment_four};
private String[] names = {"Fragment 1", "Fragment 2", "Fragment 3", "Fragment 4"};
private int isOffline;
private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
private static int currentTab = 0;
private final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tab_view_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_profile: {
            viewProfile();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.menu_sign_out: {
            signout();
            return true;
        }
        case R.id.menu_store:
            {
            startVisitingStore();
            return true;
        }
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
private void startVisitingStore(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, StoreActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

private void viewProfile() {

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    isOffline = getIntent().getIntExtra("isOffline", 0); //1 means is offline, 0 means is online
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
}


private void setupTabIcons() {

    final TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(0);
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(tabIcons[0])
            .override(42,42)
            .into(new SimpleTarget<GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, GlideAnimation<? super GlideDrawable> glideAnimation) {
                    tab.setIcon(resource);
                }
            });

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Fragment_One one = new Fragment_One();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("isOffline", isOffline);
    mainActivity.setArguments(bundle);
    adapter.addFrag(one, names[0]);

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            toolbar.setTitle(names[position]);
            currentTab = position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_One

```
public class Fragment_One extends Fragment implements GEventLoadMore {

    ......
    ......

    public void setView(final ArrayList<GEventAdapter> eventsArr) {


        listView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = listView.getItemAnimator();

        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        listView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(2));

        listView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);

        adapter = new Fragment_One_CustomAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.example, eventsArr);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        listView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (eventsArr.size() > 0) {
                    int lastVisiblePosition = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (lastVisiblePosition == recyclerView.getChildCount()) {
                        //progressDialog.show();
                        if(isOffline==0)
                            loadMoreFunction();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {


            }
        });

        restoreScrollPosition();
    }

.....
.....

}
```

Comment: make sure that you are using low-resolution image

Comment: I am using respective res for respective dpis.

Comment: Your title says ViewPager Lagging but in your question, it says RecyclerView Lagging ?

Comment: Yes , that is because the recyclerview is lagging but my fragment is alright . So that could only mean that my viewpager is faulty

Comment: put nestedscroll to false

Comment: Already done that @Mohamed

Comment: did you found a answer???

Answer (score 1):

If your recyclerView is lagging loading images , then may be your image sizes may be large then try to compress your image size. You can compress your images using Android asset studio which will convert your images to different sizes according to all different devices.
Android asset studio :- https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: The recyclerview isn't having issues loading the images. When i display the fragment on its own there is no issue . However when i show it in a viewpager , it starts to lag.thats the issue I'm facing

Comment: adapter is set on onCreateView(), that slows down swiping, because  images in recyclerView have to load each time you swipe, because new fragments are being created.                                                                                                   Refer to this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644853/viewpager-adapter-in-fragment-laggy-swiping