# Refresh ListView after deleting an item

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, refresh

I have got a database of countries and international organizations. Each country can be a member of a number of the organizations and each organization has at least one member (in other words , many-to-many). I use the well-known [LoaderManager framework](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) for displaying. But after I
delete an item (some items), all the fragments show the deleted items. I've tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager) from the `onContextItemSelected` of `MyFragment extends SherlockListFragment` class but nothing has happened.

**SOLVED.**

I had a lot of fun trying to find out the cause. I found it at last. If I use a URI `Uris.MY_URI` as a parameter of [the CursorLoader constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#CursorLoader%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29), I will have to use the same URI when [deleting.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#delete%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) I am sure that there is a more elegant solution but this one works. And I don't even need to call [the restartLoader method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#restartLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29).

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle loaderExtras) {
    // Some code
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Uris.MY_URI, mProjection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String selection = Columns._ID + "=?";
    String selectionArgs[] = new String[] {
            Long.toString(id)
    };
    long rows = getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(Uris.MY_URI, selection, selectionArgs);

    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
}
```

Don't forget about `cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);` before you return a cursor in [the query method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) and about

```
if (result > 0) {
        // result is the number of deleted items
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
}
```

in [the delete method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#delete%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Can you add your `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks#onCreateLoader(...)` code?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken, I corrected my question. There was a wrong GitHub link and I added the code to my question.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with this.  Have you stepped through to see that the items are actually being deleted from the content provider?

Comment: @JamesMcCracken, data is actually deleted from the database. The cause of the bug is the following: if each fragment has its own data, the bug will show and if all the fragments have the same data, the `ListView` will be refreshed even if I don't call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` or `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this)`