# getActivity() returns null in fragment when i override onBackPressed in parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-context

I have an Activity with few tabs managed by ViewPager. And there is one tab where i'd like to prevent closing activity when users click BACK button. Instead it loads upper level of data.

So my code in FragmentActivity looks like this

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    boolean allowQuit = true;

    if (mTabsAdapter != null){
        if(mTabsAdapter.getItem(mTabsAdapter.selectedTab) instanceof backPressOverrider){
            allowQuit = ((backPressOverrider)mTabsAdapter.getItem(mTabsAdapter.selectedTab)).onCustomBackPressed();
        }
    }

    if (allowQuit) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

And it works - activity not finished and I see my fragment, but getActivity()in my fragment returns null. None of onDetach,onStop, onDestroy,.. was fired in fragment.

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: what are you doing inside that method `.onCustomBackPressed()` are you calling any super methods? Have you checked if the fragment is still attached to the activity after that?

Comment: Without seeing your adapter I'm assuming that `getItem()` simply creates a new fragment, one that is not attached to any `Activity`, and is not returning any of the fragment used by `ViewPager`'s adapter.

Comment: Luksprog, looks like you're right Here is getItem


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        abInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
}

Comment: Then you need to retrieve the current fragment directly from the `ViewPager`. Have a look at the top answers from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager

Comment: Yup! That's exactly what i did after your comment and it works perfect!Thank you @Luksprog !