# android ViewPager how to list all current fragments and execute method for them

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I'm Android programmer making first steps. In my app I decided to use ViewPager (support.v4).

I create all fragments in very typical way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

(...)
        //let's initialize view pager
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(new MainActivitySelectDatabase());
        fragments.add(new MainActivityDetails());
        mainActivityPageAdapter = new MainActivityPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        mainActivityViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_view_pager);
        mainActivityViewPager.setAdapter(mainActivityPageAdapter);
(...)

    }
```

Next I would like to inform all fragments about one event in the following way:

```
protected void informAllFragmentsWhenDatabaseStatusChanged () {
    for (int i=0; i<mainActivityPageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ((InterfaceMainDatabaseStatusChanged) mainActivityPageAdapter.getItem(i)).onMainDatabaseStatusChanged();
    }
```

}

And everything seems to work ok if I don't change screen orientation. When I change it everything becomes crazy. Methods like getActivity or getApplication in Fragment returns null. I'm guessing that for unknown reasons the method is executed for old version of my fragments, not for the new ones. How should it be solved? How to list current versions of all Fragments from main Activity?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing that for unknown reasons the method is executed for old
>   version of my fragments, not for the new ones.

Those unknown reasons are that the `ViewPager` only calls the `getItem()` method only when it doesn't have a valid instance for that page's fragment(and after a configuration change, the `ViewPager` will have references to those fragments through the `FragmentManager`). Your options are to get rid of the list of fragments and simply instantiate the proper fragment directly in the `getItem()` method(and also use a different method to access the fragments ) or to further extend the adapter so your list will always have the proper references to the fragments of the `ViewPager`.

For option one have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager). You can also implement the communication by interfaces, registering each of the fragments of the `ViewPager` in their `onAttach` methods with the activity in some sort of `WeakReference` structure(and using this when needing to access the fragments).

To further extend the adapter have a look at the `instantiateItem()` method.

Comment: Great answer. I did in a very similar way as in the link you gave to me (answer of faylon).