# How to update-refresh Fragment in ViewPager by Main Activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm building an App that use Fragment and a single `MainActivity` that showing different fragments in the same ViewPager to replicate the behaviour of a typical MVC application.

The problem is that haven't understood how could I update the fragment programmatically to update the `ViewPager` with the new Fragment changes

For example I have this `Fragment` that show a chart, (in my intention) when I invoke `setFragment(int interval, Point[] snodePoint)` from the main, the chart should be updated in `ViewPager`

```
public class LineFragment extends Fragment {
    static int interval;
    static Point snodePoints[];


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_linegraph, container,
                false);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        ChartConfig cg = bundle.getParcelable("FragmentData");

        snodePoints = cg.getPoints();
        interval= cg.getInterval();
        Line l = new Line();

        for(int i=0; i<snodePoints.length; i++){
          LinePoint p = new LinePoint();
          Point sp=snodePoints[i];
          p.setX(sp.getX());
          p.setY(sp.getY());
          l.addPoint(p)
        }
        l.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        LineGraph li = (LineGraph) v.findViewById(R.id.linegraph);
        li.addLine(l);
        li.setRangeY(0, interval);
        li.setLineToFill(0);

        li.setOnPointClickedListener(new OnPointClickedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(int lineIndex, int pointIndex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        return v;
    }
}
```

In few words I need to

- 1-create a fragment based on the data received by the main activity.
- 2-change the data of the fragment everytime in the main activity happens
  something like setFragment(...) with new data (generated always by the main).

How could I do this?

The Main Activity with the FragmentAdapter

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
MyFragmentAdapter mMyFragmentAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    final ActionBar bar = this.getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    LineFragment lineFrag = new LineFragment();
    BarFragment barFrag = new BarFragment();
    PieFragment pieFrag = new PieFragment();

    mMyFragmentAdapter = new MyFragmentAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mMyFragmentAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Line"), LineFragment.class,
            null, lineFrag);
    mMyFragmentAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Bar"), BarFragment.class,
            null, barFrag);
    mMyFragmentAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Pie"), PieFragment.class,
            null, pieFrag);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mMyFragmentAdapter.getCount() - 1);
}

public static class MyFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private final MainActivity mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFrag = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public MyFragmentAdapter(MainActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args,
            Fragment frag) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mFrag.add(frag);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ChartConfig cg = new ChartConfig(interval, snodePoint);
        args.putParcelable("FragmentData", cg);
        Fragment f = mFrag.get(position);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

}

The first time that I create the fragment, the main activity pass successful the parameters to the Fragment through the overrided `getItem(int position)`, but if I try to change the data, also if I try to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter `mMyFragmentAdapter`, nothing happens and the fragments in `ViewPager` continue to use the same data passed in creation.

**EDIT**

Following some partial code seen in other question about fragment update I have also tried this

```
public void update() {
        try{
            LineFragment fragment = 
                      (LineFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
                                   "android:switcher:"+R.id.view_pager+":0");
                  if(fragment != null)
                  {
                     if(fragment.getView() != null) 
                     {

                        fragment.updateDisplay();
                     }
                  }
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Assuming that 0 is the id of the first Fragment-Tab fragment(I'm not sure about this kind of operation), but `fragment.updateDisplay();` is not invoked.

Comment: You didn't searched to much didn't you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager

Comment: @Luksprog mmm It's a bit different from what I have asked for. I need to understand how the Fragment can get the data passed by main, maybe I'm missing something but really I haven't understood how could I do this. If I try to create a custom constructor for my 'LineFragment' I get the error 'This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)'

Comment: @AndreaF check dialog fragment http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html uses a static `static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num)` to which param is passed and then uses set and get arguments. and you pass the value like `newInstance(value)` if that is what you meany by passing data from main to fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks but DialogFragment is a fragment that displays a dialog window floating on top of its activity's window, that is not my case

Comment: @AndreaF concept is the same apply it to fragment

Comment: @Raghunandan But if the Fragment cannot have any contructor different from default constructor in what way I could solve my problem? DialogFragment use an int to identificate different istance. From what I know fragment cannot.

Comment: @AndreaF is DialogFragment not fragment? But i guess that is not what you need seems the answer below is what you need. However your understanding of fragment is wrong

Comment: @Raghunandan ok you are right, now I have understood what you mean

Answer (score 61):

In your Adapter override getItemPosition

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

After that

```
viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
```

should work.

Comment: @Nino Handler.. Does that notifyDataSetChanged in the adapter refresh all the fragments or the only fragment which will visible to the user..

Comment: all which are currently attached - if you use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter this might not be the case for all fragments

Comment: @RajaJawahar this will updated current fragment

Answer (score 3):

> I need to understand how the Fragment can get the data passed by main,
>   maybe I'm missing something but really I haven't understood how could
>   I do this.

From this it seems that you want to pass the data at the moment of the creation of the `Fragment`. If this is what you want you shouldn't make a custom constructor(and generally for a `Fragment` you should have only the default no-args constructor(because the platform needs it to recreate the `Fragment` at certain times)).

Instead you should either pass the data in a [`Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html):

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     switch (position) {
        //...
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.put("a_string_representing_theKey", data)
        LineFragment f = new LineFragment();
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
        //...
     } 
}
```

This will only work if the data can be put in a `Bundle`(see the `put...` method of the `Bundle` class, all primitives + objects that are `Parcelable`). In the fragment you could then retrieve the arguments using `getArguments()`.

You can also make the `Fragment` retrieve the data directly from the `Activity`:

```
// in the lifecycle method where you want the data
((MainActivity)getActivity()).getDataForFragment(); // use the data
```

> For example I have this Fragment that show a chart, (in my intention)
>   when I invoke setFragment(int interval, Point[] snodePoint) from the
>   main, the chart should be updated in ViewPager

You seem to contradict yourself. For this use the code from the question I linked to, of course just calling your current `setFragment()` method will not do anything as you just update the value of two variables, you'll need to let the UI know about the change(like calling another method to recreate the view hierarchy, setting the new values on the chart view and calling `invalidate()` etc).

Edit:

The code used in the question I linked to should work, but you aren't using the proper code. You have a **`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`** but you're using the code for a `FragmentPagerAdapter` which will not work:

```
FragmentStatePagerAdapter a = (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
LineFragment f = (LineFragment) a.instantiateItem(pager, thePositionYouWant);
```

Keep in mind that the code above will work only for the visible fragment plus 1 fragment on each side, the other fragments will not be available(and as the user doesn't see them or can't move to them right away they shouldn't be updated).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In few words I need to 1-create a fragment based on the data received by the mainactivity. 2-change the data of the fragment everytime if in the main happens something like 'setFragment(...)'. If i can do this using the Bundle, could you give me more details about how to use this with Fragment?

Comment: @AndreaF I've edited my answer a bit. You could look at any basic tutorials to see how to use the `Bundle` as a fragment's arguments.

Comment: @Raghunandan The `getItem()` method is from the `FragmentPagerAdapter`/`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` where he creates the `Fragment` and you can't make it `static`.

Comment: @Luksprog yup understood now i guess i misunderstood the question. i thought its a fragment. getItem here is a overriden method of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: @Luksprog now I have understood how to pass the parameters from main activity to Fragment, but unfortunately if I try to change the data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` nothing happens

Comment: @AndreaF Are you calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `MyFragmentAdapter` to update the `LineFragment`? If yes, don't do this, use the code from the question I linked to to reference the `LineFragment`, call the `setFragment()` method to set the variables and update the data(for example by resetting the view and rebuilding it).

Comment: @Luksprog Please, could you give me a sample? I have tried to follow the step in the link but without success. I have also tried to use `myadapter.destroyItem(mViewPager, 0, LineFragment.class);` but maybe I have passed the wrong parameters in the `destroyItem` method because crashes

Comment: I have updated the question with more details of my main activity

Comment: @AndreaF You want to update the data of the adapter's fragments not not replace the fragments themselves. In the question I linked to there is some code on **how to access a fragment** from the `ViewPager` to call update methods on it.

Comment: @Luksprog right I want to update the fragment, but since I have no success with this approach I have also tried to replace the fragments. However still are not able to access and update the Fragment. The method of the accepted answer in the link doesn't work (is unclear how and where the HomeListFragment is implemented)
The 2nd top answer method returns NullPointerException if i try to get any data from the declared `FragmentStatePagerAdapter a = (FragmentStatePagerAdapter) pager.getAdapter();` and if i try something like `a.startUpdate(mViewPager);` doesn't happen anything

Comment: @Luksprog Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 3):

very simple to override the method in the fragment

@Override

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser){

        actionView();
    }
    else{
        //no
    }

}
```

Comment: this method is deprecated, so any alternative ?

Answer (score 3):

How to update-refresh Fragment in View Pager by Main Activity programmatically
after long struggle I have found proper solution

```
tablayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                
                refreshTab(tab.getPosition());// create a method
                viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
 private void refreshTab(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
    
  
            break;
        case 1:
            
            CompaniesInterest comP1 = (CompaniesInterest) viewpager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewpager, viewpager.getCurrentItem());
            comP1.refreshpage();
            break;
        case 2:
            
            TotalSelectedCompanies toTal = (TotalSelectedCompanies) viewpager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewpager, viewpager.getCurrentItem());
            toTal.refreshpage();
           
    }
}
// Create a interface for refresh data for fragmen
public interface Refreshpage {
    void refreshpage();
}
// implements Refreshpage interface in both fragment TotalSelectedCompanies and CompaniesInterest
//
@Override`enter code here`
    public void refreshpage() {
        // do what you want to refresh 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is work for Kotlin**

Inside the Viewpager Adapter use this:-

```
  val viewPagerAdapter = ViewpagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)

    view_pager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
```

In-side the fragment use this :-

```
override fun setMenuVisibility(menuVisible: Boolean) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible)
   // hit API
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
     // hit API
}
```