# Accessing a fragment from a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using the following simple `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and I want to get a reference to one of the fragments, keeping in mind that they may have been destroyed.

```
public class MyStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int count;

    public MyStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int count) {
        super(fm);
        this.count= count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return MyFragment1.newInstance();

            case 1:
                return MyFragment2.newInstance();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379165/update-data-in-listfragment-as-part-of-viewpager/8886019#8886019) question, whose second answer says that if you call `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instatiateItem` and there is already a reference to the fragment, it will not call `getItem()` again. I looked at the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java) and to my understanding this is indeed what happens.

However, I was wondering, can I do something like the following? It seems straightforward enough, but the fact that I haven't seen it being used anywhere makes me suspicious that something is really wrong that I just can't see.

So basically my question is: What would be the errors in using something like the following to access the fragment?

```
public class MyStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int count;
    private MyFragment1 myFragment1;
    private MyFragment2 myFragment2;

    public MyStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int count) {
        super(fm);
        this.count= count;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {

        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                if (myFragment1 == null) {
                    myFragment1 = MyFragment1.newInstance();
                }
                return myFragment1;
            case 1:
               if (myFragment2 == null) {
                   myFragment2 = MyFragment2.newInstance();
               }
               return myFragment2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

And to get it, I would call `getItem(position)`.

Comment: You can also use Fragment.instantiate()

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see with that approach is `myFragment1` and `myFragment2` not being `null`. Let's say you get rid of the `null` check. The problem there would be that you will generate a new `Fragment` every time you call `getItem()`.

Another problem that I see is that `getItem()` will always return `null`. You have no `break` statements in your `switch`, so it will go all the way to the `default` case which is `null`. If you add the corresponding `breaks` then the code shouldn't compile until you add corresponding `return` statements after the `if(){...}`s.

Also, I would suggest you get into the habit of adding meaningful names to the parameters of your methods.

Comment: Yes, that's why I did the null check modification to getItem(). So if I use it as is (with the null check I mean) are there any other issues that you could see?

Comment: You are right about the break, I overlooked it, code updated. However I was wondering if something more fundamental is wrong, memory management-wise.