# Synchronise data across multiple activities/fragments

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have three components whose data I have to synchronise.

1. **Activity** - This activity get data from `Content Provider` and has a `ViewPager`. It passes this data (`Fragment.getInstance(data...)`) to the second component which is a `Fragment`
2. **Fragment** - This fragment has a `RecyclerView` and `onClick()` of a particular item, data is passed through intent to the third component which is an `Activity`.
3. **Activity** -  Here the data which is received is modified.

What would be the best way to sync this modification across all the three components?

Comment: You can use interface callbacks or any third party library like otto

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi worst advice :( This is totally against how android components are supposed to be used. It breaks modularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not hold references to the same POJOs (Plain old java object) between different activities and fragments. Use shared preferences or a SQL db instead.

Activities and fragments are supposed to be [stateless](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/stateless). So I am going to tell you how to **transfer** data between activities and fragments rather than how to **synchronize** data.

Let's take them case by case:

- **'1 to 2':** You probably already have all the fragments in the activity. So just call `fragment.sendData(...)` to send data to the fragment. *Caveat:* In case you are using a `FragmentStateAdapter` you will have to do this [(reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8886019/1396264):

  ```
  if (adapter.getCount() > 0) {
      fragment = (MyFragment) adapter.instantiateItem(
              null, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
      // A NullPointerException is thrown if the item isn't initialized as yet
      // So be careful.
  }
  ```
- **'2 to 1':** Create a fragment callback interface (say `FragmentCallback`) that the *activity1* must implement i.e. override `Fragment.onAttach(Activity activty)`, check if `activity instanceof FragmentCallback` and throw an exception if it isn't. (This is automatically generated by android studio when you create a new fragment)
- **'1 to 3':**  Start the activity by passing an `Intent` with the data.
- **'2 to 3':**  Start the activity by passing an `Intent` with the data. In case you need some data from *activity1*, don't use this method. Use '2 to 1' followed by '1 to 3' instead.
- **'3 to 1':** The correct way to do it is to start a new *activity1* with `Intent` data or send it to the original *activity1* using `startActivtyForResult` and handle the result in *activity1*. You can use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` [(ref)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) if needed. If you **have to** send it the original *activity* (in a way that cannot be satisfied by `startActivtyForResult`), it's definitely a code smell. Use shared preferences or something and check it in `Activity1.onResume` and/or `Activity1.onCreate`.
- **'3 to 2'**: Use '3 to 1', followed by '1 to 2'.

Comment: If you need data from "3 to 1" and if second activity was started by first activity (i.e. "1 to 3") then the second activity can be started for result and that activity can send data through intent result to the first activity. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong here.

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal oh yes that's correct as well. WiIl update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I adopted to the event bus library which simplified the communications. Check it out at [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)