# When sending message App crashes with this error- It works fine prior to AdMob

Tags: java, android, admob, backendless

My message app works fine until Admob is added and I am not sure how to solve the crash. There is nothing wrong with Admob; it works fine but the issue is that after i add it my app crashes. When commenting out Admob it works fine again. Please help
Here is the crash log:

```
    /com.app.androidchatsdk.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.app.androidchatsdk.app, PID: 18494
                                                                                  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.backendless.services.messaging.MessageStatus
                                                                                      at com.app.androidchatsdk.firebaseplugin.firebase.backendless.BBackendlessHandler$2.handleResponse(BBackendlessHandler.java:123)
                                                                                      at com.backendless.async.message.AsyncMessage$ResponseHandler.handle(AsyncMessage.java:64)
                                                                                      at com.backendless.async.message.AsyncMessage.handleCallback(AsyncMessage.java:41)
                                                                                      at com.backendless.core.AndroidCarrier$1.handleMessage(AndroidCarrier.java:37)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Here are the codes of how my code looks for admob; at the end is the code that we will be directed to when app crashes (blue link):
```

1.XML page

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/googleAds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

here is the main activity:

```
    public class ChatSDKMainActivity extends ChatSDKBaseActivity {

        private static final String TAG = ChatSDKMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        private static boolean DEBUG = Debug.MainActivity;
        private ExitHelper exitHelper;
        private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
        private ViewPager pager;
        protected AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter adapter;
        private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
        private AdView adView;

        private static final String FIRST_TIME_IN_APP = "First_Time_In_App";
        public static final String PAGE_ADAPTER_POS = "page_adapter_pos";

        public static final String Action_Contacts_Added = "com.app.androidchatsdk.action.contact_added";
        public static final String Action_clear_data = "com.app.androidchatsdk.action.logged_out";
        public static final String Action_Refresh_Fragment = "com.app.androidchatsdk.action.refresh_fragment";

        private int pageAdapterPos = -1;

        private OpenFromPushChecker mOpenFromPushChecker;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            exitHelper = new ExitHelper(this);

            if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0) {
                // Activity was brought to front and not created,
                // Thus finishing this will get us to the last viewed activity
                finish();
                return;
            }

            setContentView(R.layout.chat_sdk_activity_view_pager);

            firstTimeInApp();
            initViews();



            enableCheckOnlineOnResumed(true);

            if (!fromLoginActivity && savedInstanceState != null) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(PAGE_ADAPTER_POS));
            }

            mOpenFromPushChecker = new OpenFromPushChecker();
            if (mOpenFromPushChecker.checkOnCreate(getIntent(), savedInstanceState)) {
                startChatActivityForID(getIntent().getExtras().getLong(ChatSDKAbstractChatActivity.THREAD_ID));
                return;
            }


        }



        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            ChatSDKThreadPool.getInstance().execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getNetworkAdapter().getEventManager().removeEventByTag(appEventListener.getTag());
                    getNetworkAdapter().getEventManager().addEvent(appEventListener);

                    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                        private int lastPage = 0;
                        private int refreshContactsInterval = 4000;
                        private long lastContactsRefresh = 0;

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    //                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onPageScrolled");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            if (DEBUG)
                                Timber.v("onPageSelected, Pos: %s, Last: %s", position, lastPage);

                            pageAdapterPos = position;

                            lastPage = position;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    //                if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "onPageScrollStateChanged");
                        }
                    });

                    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Action_Contacts_Added);
                    intentFilter.addAction(Action_clear_data);
                    intentFilter.addAction(Action_Refresh_Fragment);

                    registerReceiver(mainReceiver, intentFilter);
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);

            if (mOpenFromPushChecker == null)
                mOpenFromPushChecker = new OpenFromPushChecker();

            if (mOpenFromPushChecker.checkOnNewIntent(intent)) {
                startChatActivityForID(intent.getExtras().getLong(ChatSDKAbstractChatActivity.THREAD_ID));
                return;
            }

            if (adapter != null) {
                ChatSDKBaseFragment pro = getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Profile), conv = getFragment(PagerAdapterTabs.Conversations);

                if (conv != null)
                    conv.refreshOnBackground();

                if (pro != null)
                    pro.refresh();
            }
        }

        private AppEventListener appEventListener = new AppEventListener("MainActivity") {
            private final int messageDelay = 3000;
            private UIUpdater uiUpdaterMessages;

            @Override
            public boolean onMessageReceived(final BMessage message) {

                // Only notify for private threads.
                if (message.getThread().getTypeSafely() == BThread.Type.Public) {
                    return false;
                }

                // Make sure the message that incoming is not the user message.
                if (message.getBUserSender().getEntityID().equals(
                        BNetworkManager.sharedManager().getNetworkAdapter().currentUserModel().getEntityID()))
                    return false;

                if (uiUpdaterMessages != null)
                    uiUpdaterMessages.setKilled(true);

                handler.removeCallbacks(uiUpdaterMessages);

                uiUpdaterMessages = new UIUpdater() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!isKilled()) {
                            // We check to see that the ChatActivity is not listening to this messages so we wont alert twice.
                            if (!getNetworkAdapter().getEventManager().isEventTagExist(ChatSDKChatActivity.MessageListenerTAG + message.getThread())) {
                                // Checking if the message has a sender with a name, Also if the message was read.
                                if (message.getBUserSender().getMetaName() != null && !message.wasRead()) {
                                    NotificationUtils.createMessageNotification(ChatSDKMainActivity.this, message);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                handler.postDelayed(uiUpdaterMessages, messageDelay);

                return false;
            }
        };

        static final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putInt(PAGE_ADAPTER_POS, pageAdapterPos);
            mOpenFromPushChecker.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }

        private void initViews() {
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

            tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

            // Only creates the adapter if it wasn't initiated already
            if (adapter == null)
                adapter = new PagerAdapterTabs(getFragmentManager());

            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            tabs.setViewPager(pager);

            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_chat_sdk, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.android_settings) {

                // FIXME Clearing the cache, Just for debug.
                /*final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

                VolleyUtils.getBitmapCache().resize(1);
                VolleyUtils.getBitmapCache().resize(maxMemory / 8);*/
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.contact_developer) {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(BDefines.ContactDeveloper_Email)) {
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
                            "mailto", BDefines.ContactDeveloper_Email, null));
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, BDefines.ContactDeveloper_Subject);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, BDefines.ContactDeveloper_DialogTitle));
                }
                return true;
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.setup_guide) {
    //            Uri uri = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
    //            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    //            startActivity(intent);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/lsJRFAPeM9I");

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://youtu.be/lsJRFAPeM9I"));
                // openVideo.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com"), uri);
                //  openVideo.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(video), "video/*");

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            // If the register did not had a chance to register due to orientation change.
            try {
                unregisterReceiver(mainReceiver);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // No need to handle the exception.
            }
        }

        private void firstTimeInApp() {
            if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(FIRST_TIME_IN_APP, true)) {
                // Creating the images directory if not exist.
                Utils.ImageSaver.getAlbumStorageDir(this, BDefines.ImageDirName);

                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean(FIRST_TIME_IN_APP, false).apply();
            }
        }


        /**
         * Refresh the contacts fragment when a contact added action is received.
         * Clear Fragments data when logged out.
         * Refresh Fragment when wanted.
         */
        private BroadcastReceiver mainReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Action_Contacts_Added)) {
                    ChatSDKBaseFragment contacts = getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Contacts);

                    if (contacts != null)
                        contacts.refreshOnBackground();

                    if (intent.getExtras().containsKey(ChatSDKSearchActivity.USER_IDS_LIST)) {
                        String[] ids = intent.getStringArrayExtra(ChatSDKSearchActivity.USER_IDS_LIST);
                        for (String id : ids)
                            getNetworkAdapter().getEventManager().userMetaOn(id, null);
                    }
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Action_clear_data)) {
                    clearData();
                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Action_Refresh_Fragment)) {
                    if (intent.getExtras() == null)
                        return;

                    if (!intent.getExtras().containsKey(PAGE_ADAPTER_POS))
                        return;

                    int fragment = intent.getExtras().getInt(PAGE_ADAPTER_POS);

                    ChatSDKBaseFragment frag = getFragment(fragment);

                    if (frag != null)
                        frag.refresh();

                } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ChatSDKAbstractChatActivity.ACTION_CHAT_CLOSED)) {
                    getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Conversations).loadDataOnBackground();
                }
            }
        };

        private void clearData() {
            ChatSDKBaseFragment contacts = getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Contacts);

            if (contacts != null)
                contacts.clearData();

            ChatSDKBaseFragment conv = getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Conversations);

            if (conv != null)
                conv.clearData();

            ChatSDKBaseFragment pro = getFragment(AbstractChatSDKTabsAdapter.Profile);

            if (pro != null)
                pro.clearData();
        }

        /* Exit Stuff*/
        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            exitHelper.triggerExit();
        }

        /**
         * After screen orientation chage the getItem from the fragment page adapter is no null but it is not visible to the user
         * so we have to use this workaround so when we call any method on the wanted fragment the fragment will respond.
         * http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393477/2568492
         */
        private ChatSDKBaseFragment getFragment(int index) {
            return ((ChatSDKBaseFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + index));
        }



    }



    private void loadGoogleAds_banner() {
MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ID");
AdView aAdView = (AdView) findViewByID(R.id.googleAds);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
aAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
}
```

Code we will be directed to when app crashes:

```
  Backendless.Messaging.publish(channel, data.toString(), publishOptions, deliveryOptions, new AsyncCallback<MessageStatus>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(MessageStatus response) {
                if (DEBUG) Timber.v("Message published to channel: " + channel);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {
                if (DEBUG) Timber.v("Publish failed, " + fault.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public Promise uploadFile(byte[] data, String name, String mimeType) {
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is admob error. What code is @ line 123 in file  BBackendlessHandler.java

Comment: the code @123 is --> Backendless.Messaging.publish(channel, data.toString(), publishOptions, deliveryOptions, new AsyncCallback<MessageStatus>() {

Comment: ^ Please edit your question for additional details (including the missing material right at the end) - it is not particularly readable in comments.

Comment: error has nothing to do with Admob. Check your code for Backendless.. Saw lot of messages on their support forum. Update your question for error with Backendless messaging and someone will guide you

Comment: Amod correct it's not related to admob; could it be a dictionary that was added on it and @halfer going to add the remaining code

Comment: It's not related to backendless, I tried to add a custom suggestion could that be the one creating the error? -again i am new bee apology if i am not making sense

Comment: Hello again -  somehow error is related to admob. B/c even if admob implementation works fine to view ads, problem of crash arises when admob is added. When admob is commented, the app starts to run perfectly fine

Comment: @Amod you were right nothing to do with admob, I tried to recreate from scratch by avoiding the backendless and it seems like the error was gone without it. Now seems like it's backendless this thing is leading to no solution though please help

Comment: @To.vi no idea about backendless.. Create a new query with logs and your code and tagging it to backendless

Comment: @Amod - as per your suggestion, I have tagged Backendless and Admob