# How to disable AdMob on a page

Tags: android, admob

How can you disable admob on a page: this is how i implemented it in XML and main activity (of course i have string with Ad-id:

XML below:

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/AdsArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Main activity below:

```
  private void loadGoogleAds() {
        LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.AdsArea);
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        rootLayout.addView(adView, 0);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding `AdView` programatically, I think to remove `ads` don't  call `loadGoogleAds()` from your `Activity`.

OR, you can hide `AdView` using:

```
if (adView.getVisibility() == AdView.VISIBLE)
    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

OR, remove `adView` from `rootLayout` using:

```
rootLayout.removeViewAt(0);
```

Comment: so this will remove the ad in one page not the whole ad right?

Comment: (It says can't resolve to method for "setVisibility" -main goal is to stop call of admob or any activity when when user leave the admob viewing activity

Comment: Following are the errors: Error:(40, 25) error: <identifier> expected                                                          Error:(40, 35) error: <identifier> expected                                     Error:Execution failed for task ':sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Thanks your updated answer works to hide Ad. But i was trying to use to to solve the problem i am having where when i add admob to my app it crashes as per this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766980/when-sending-message-app-crashes-with-this-error-it-works-fine-prior-to-admob) how can i get the backendless not to notice the admob so that it won't crash

Comment: I have seen your question. It seems different from admob. I will try to give a solution. But i think my answer resolved your current question. So its better to mark my answer as accepted and if seems useful give an up vote also. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have marked your answer as acceted for the question here  and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Happy to help you. You can give an up-vote if my answer seems useful to you. Thanks in advance :)